# Show all Properties of a class in a Listbox

Tags: wpf, reflection, listbox

I would like to create a listbox containing several properties (similar to this tutorial http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html). However my control needs to be more flexible - i would like to pass different objects to my ViewModel in runtime and the listbox should list all .NET Properties of these objects (mListObject).
This sounds an awful lot like reflection which i did never use yet, so i was tempted to implement this in a less flexible way.

The obvious problem that i am running into is that mListObject does not contain a list of .NET Properties which i can bind to my Listbox. However, the tutorial linked above seems to access such a list of dependencyProperties which made me think that maybe there is an easier way than reflection to get a hold on all my properties.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?
Binding the properties to the listbox one-by-one is still an option for me here (it's just a handful properties), but obviously it's less flexible and elegant.